# What's the best way to convert an int to a char in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and I was wondering what the best, convenient, readable, fastest way of doing it is.

Example: 5 -> '5'

My best approach for now is:

```
c = string(i)[1]
```

or

```
c = char('0'+i)
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with your `Char`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Final goal was to replace some digits of an integer with another digit. e.g. 35294 -> 31114
Using a character while dealing with integers seems unrelated, but my intention was secondary to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed second answer is easy to understand, correct (for latin numerals!), and fast.

```
digittochar(d) = Char('0' + d)
```

Depending on the expected cleanliness of the upstream data, you might add some checks to make sure you don't get something unexpected; after all

```
digittochar(6002) = អ
```

Comment: As of Julia 1.5, the Char() isn't needed: `'0' + d` results in a Char directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Julia `function` that will replace digits within an integer, here's one way to do it.  There's really no error checking so this is fragile to nutty inputs.

```
julia> function replace_int_digs{T <: Union(BigInt, Unsigned, Signed)}(x::T, locs::Vector{Int}, digs::Vector{Int})                                        
           x_str_array = split(string(x), "")                                                                                                             
           for (k, loc) in enumerate(locs)                                                                                                                
               x_str_array[loc] = string(digs[k])                                                                                                         
           end                                                                                                                                            
           return parseint(T, join(x_str_array))                                                                                                          
       end                                                                                                                                                
replace_int_digs (generic function with 1 method)                                                                                                         

julia> replace_int_digs(12345,[3],[9])                                                                                                                    
12945                                                                                                                                                     

julia> replace_int_digs(big(12345),[3],[9])                                                                                                               
12945                                                                                                                                                     

julia> replace_int_digs(big(12345),[3,1],[9,7])                                                                                                           
72945                                                                                                                                                     

julia> replace_int_digs(int32(12345),[3,1],[9,7])                                                                                                         
72945
```